# How do you initialize/use UITableViewCells with CellStyle = .value1 programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I want to use Apple's given Cell Style [`value1`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/cellstyle/value1) for my cells and I am not sure how this is done correctly. The only possible way to set the cell style is during the [Cell's initialization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623276-init), but I don't think subclassing should be necessary in this case.

What would be the correct way to set the CellType?
I tried to get it done in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`, but `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)` does not return an Optional, which is why my logic cannot work.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCellIdentifier", for: indexPath)

    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell.init(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: "myCellIdentifier")
    }

    // setup cell text and so on
    // ...

    return cell
}
```

Comment: What stops your from setting up the cell in needed style using Storyboard? I think the correct style is called "Right Detail" Then is just enough to dequeue it in a regular way.

Comment: @VladislavKovalyov I am currently learning how to programmatically create the UI and want to move away from Storyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call `tableView.register(...)`

Instead, use this approach in `cellForRowAt`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // try to dequeue a cell
    var cv1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cv1")

    // if that fails, create a new one
    if cv1 == nil {
        cv1 = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.value1, reuseIdentifier: "cv1")
    }

    // just for sanity
    guard let cell = cv1 else { fatalError("Failed to get a cell!") }

    // set the cell properties as desired
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .yellow
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Row \(indexPath.row)"
    return cell

}
```

Comment: Thanks this looks good. I will try it out on Monday and mark it as the correct answer after testing. Out of curiosity: I would get the same result by creating a cell subclass and overriding it’s `init(style:reuseIdentifier:)` by calling `super.init(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)` with my original code, correct?

Comment: In general, it's a good idea to create your own cell subclass anyway. Suppose you decide later to add other elements? If you've subclassed a cell, that's where you'll make your change. Otherwise, you'll have to restructure your code. (Sure, probably not a big deal... but thinking ahead.)